# What does all these countries have in common?

Tags: pattern, knowledge

What does all these countries have in common?

- Botswana
- Costa Rica
- Georgia
- Honduras
- Jamaica
- Japan
- Latvia
- Macedonia
- Nigeria
- Peru
- Switzerland
- Thailand
- Trinidad and Tobago
- England
- Israel
- Laos
- Austria
- Scotland
- United Kingdom

I have add more countries with same properties, 
I think they are the only countries, with the properties.

> Sorry there is a mistake, Libya is not among them. 
>   I used old data, so I was wrong.

Comment: They all have an "a"! ... oh wait...

Comment: @boboquack ha.. ha... United Kingdom doesn't have it!

Comment: they are all above sea level

Comment: Are those the only countries? Or can more countries be added to the list? I have a feeling it's gonna be too broad in the latter case...

Comment: @Lolgast :  Yes I think they are the only country.

Comment: All countries have trees

Comment: Micronesia must also get into this list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it:

> all of flags are symmetric.
>  So, no matter you put the flags, there is no upside down.

Comment: Costa Rica and Trinidad and Tobago don't have this property.

Comment: @RickvanOsta : Their Flags have varians, and the varians is symetric.

Comment: Your last edit isn't true, at least not for Trinidad and Tobago and for the UK. All flags can be rotated by 180° and stay the same, though. (But you wouldn't be able to attach them to a flagpole if they were real flags.)

Comment: @shree.pat18 The flag of Bangladesh is not symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> white color, because the flags of all the listed countries have white color in it.

Comment: No, but you are on the right track